# How to migrate SharePoint 2007 publishing site to 2010 with modified Pages list?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a number of SharePoint 2007 publishing sites that I'm migrating to SharePoint 2010. The sites were customized through a site feature so that the "Pages" doument library is titled "Web Pages". This is causing 2010 to throw errors about "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

If I manually create a "Pages" document library, the error goes away. Is there something in 2010 that is specifically looking for a list named "Pages", and if so, how can I change it to look for "Web Pages" instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that renaming Pages library is even supported ? There are many things bound to fail:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/936910

Comment: I don't know if it's supported or not, but that's the way our 2007 install was setup when I inherited it :(

Comment: If you are now migrating the farm to 2010, I would recommend considering this in the mind. You might want to check if this is a supported scenario. Seems to me its not since Pages library is "special" library in SharePoint.